# TextBox display closest match string

Tags: c#, string, textbox

How can I get the `string` from a list that best match with a base `string` using the Levenshtein Distance.

This is my code:

```
{
    string basestring = "Coke 600ml";
    List<string> liststr = new List<string>
    {
        "ccoca cola",
        "cola",
        "coca cola 1L",
        "coca cola 600",
        "Coke 600ml",
        "coca cola 600ml",
    };

    Dictionary<string, int> resultset = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach(string test in liststr)
    {
        resultset.Add(test, Ldis.Compute(basestring, test));
    }

    int minimun = resultset.Min(c => c.Value);

    var closest = resultset.Where(c => c.Value == minimun); 

    Textbox1.Text = closest.ToString();           
}
```

In this example if I run the code I get 0 changes in string number 5 from the list, so how can I display in the `TextBox` the `string` itself?

for exemple : "Coke 600ml" Right now my `TextBox` just returns:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1
[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Int32]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: what Ldis.Compute doing ?

Comment: Ldis is my Levenshtein Distance Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resultset.Where()` returns a list, you should use

```
var closest = resultset.First(c => c.Value == minimun);
```

to select a single result.

Then the `closest` is a `KeyValuePair<string, int>`, so you should use

```
Textbox1.Text = closest.Key;
```

to get the string. (You added the string as `Key` and changes count as `Value` to `resultset` earilier)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var closest = resultset.First(c => c.Value == minimun);
```

Your existing code is trying to display a list of items in the textbox. I looks like it should just grab a single item where Value == min

Answer (score 0):

There is a good solution in code project
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36869/Fuzzy-Search

Answer (score 0):

It can be very much simplified like so:

```
var res = liststr.Select(x => new {Str = x, Dist = Ldis.Compute(basestring, x)})
                 .OrderBy(x => x.Dist)
                 .Select(x => x.Str)
                 .ToArray();
```

This will order the list of strings from most similar to least similar.
To only get the most similar one, simply replace `ToArray()` with `First()`.

Short explanation:

For every string in the list, it creates an anonymous type which contains the original string and it's distance, computed using the Ldis class. Then, it orders the collection by the distance and maps back to the original string, so as to lose the "extra" information calculated for the ordering.

Comment: I'll give this code a try. But for now I marked @Simon Chan as the  answer.

Comment: Thanks, this code also works very well. I just marked @Simon Chan as the answer because it was the quickest approach to my question and code.